# Where should I put AutoLayout code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout

I'm using `PureLayout` to implement AutoLayout of subviews in a UIView. But I don't know the best practice of organizing the code.

Should I put the AutoLayout related code in the *init* of the UIView, or the overridden methods such as `updateConstraints` and `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: Set up in `init` is ok

Answer (score 1):

You should add `constraints` when you are sure that `view` has been added to its `superview`. Basically, you should do it in `superview`'s class any point after `addSubview:` is called.

***To answer your questions:***

**1-** in `init` methods, can you be sure of that `view` has been added as `subview` to a `superview`? it wouldn't be safe to assume that. maybe you can add `constraints` in `init` method of `superview`

**2-** `layoutSubviews` is in where `autolayout` code actually works. you can't add `constraints` in `layoutSubviews`. already playing with `autolayout` `constraints` are not cheap, therefore you should add/remove them as few as possible, doing so in a method that is called multiple times (i.e. `layoutSubviews`) is not the best practice.

Mechanism of `autolayout` is going to inner `view` from outer `view`, so `subviews` do not actually concern about `constraints`. it is `superview`'s responsibility

Comment: But I usually make constraints in `layoutSubviews' in custom cell and it works.

Comment: it probably causes one more layout pass, it is not the best practice. if your concern is table view cell, you can consider adding constraints in awakeFromNib. Since in that case, your superview is the cell and within awakeFromNib

Answer (score 1):

For example, I want to create a subclass of UIView called PHView, and for any phview, there is a subview called centerView, it is always at the center of phview, and width/height is 0.3*phview's width/height.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/jaljggnymxliu1e/IMG_3178.jpg

```
 #import "PHView.h"
 #import "Masonry.h"
@interface PHView()
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL didUpdateConstraints;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *centerView;
@end
@implementation PHView
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
 - (UIView *)centerView {
    if (!_centerView) {
        _centerView = [UIView new];
        _centerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        [self addSubview:_centerView];
    }
    return _centerView;
}

 -(void)updateConstraints {
    if (!_didUpdateConstraints) {
        _didUpdateConstraints = YES;
        [self.centerView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.centerX.equalTo(self.mas_centerX);
            make.centerY.equalTo(self.mas_centerY);
            make.width.equalTo(self.mas_width).multipliedBy(0.3);
            make.height.equalTo(self.mas_height).multipliedBy(0.3);
        }];
    }
    [super updateConstraints];
}
@end
```

'didUpdateConstraints' aims to indicate you have added constraints, so you will only add constraints once.

in UIViewController:make phview top bottom left right 20 to the margin.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    PHView *myView = [PHView new];
    [self.view addSubview:myView];
    [myView mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
        make.edges.equalTo(self.view).with.insets(UIEdgeInsetsMake(20, 20, 20, 20));
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you by understanding controller’s view hierarchy
**How View Controllers Participate in the View Layout Process**

1. The view controller’s view is resized to the new size.
2. If autolayout is not in use, the views are resized according to their autoresizing masks.
3. The view controller’s viewWillLayoutSubviews method is called.
4. The view’s layoutSubviews method is called. If autolayout is used to configure the view hierarchy, it updates the layout constraints by executing the following steps:

   > a.The view controller’s updateViewConstraints method is called.
   >
   > b.The UIViewController class’s implementation of the updateViewConstraints method calls the view’s updateConstraints method.
   >
   > c. After the layout constraints are updated, a new layout is calculated and the views are repositioned.
5. The view controller’s viewDidLayoutSubviews method is called.

Please [refer this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout/AdoptingaFull-ScreenLayout.html) for more details